# How to maintain multiple Apache Superset environments and migrate charts and dashboards

Tags: apache-superset

We are planning to maintain multiple instances of Apache Superset like one each for Development, Staging and production. The question is how do we migrate dashboards and charts created in development environment to higher environments like Staging and production ?

What is the best practice to migrate charts and dashboards from one environment to another environment ?

Thanks